# How to control data repeatation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller, duplicates, savechanges, data-controls

I have a quiz. The quiz has 10 questions. First time I saved 7 questions of the quiz using the below code.In the second case I wanted to save the quiz questions again. But in this case the data is being duplicated. I want the question that have been saved once not to be saved in the second time.

```php
     foreach($request->input('questions', []) as $key => $question){
            QuizSessionAnswer::create([
                'session_id'=> $sessionId,
                'question_id'=> $question,
                'selected_choice_id'=> $request->input('choice.'.$question),
                'created_by_id'=> auth()->user()->id,
            ]);
        }
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Well, you're using `::create()`, which is going to create a new record every time... You need to add some logic to check for a record with those IDs (all or a subset), and create or update accordingly.

Comment: what combinations of the columns make a question unique in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You can one of two

1. try `updateOrCreate` method, you can review [Laravel Reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts).
2. you need to identify in your "view form" if you will create a QUIZ questions (send to a quiz.create route) or edit your questions (send to a quiz.edit route)